# change folder name after find text in *.oeaccount file

Tags: xml, batch-file, cmd, dos, rename

I have `*.oeaccount` files (XML files) in many folders. I want a batch file read the text in the XML file and rename the folder that contain the file.

The xml files contain text similar to the following:

```
    <SMTP_Display_Name type="SZ">abc@cba.com</SMTP_Display_Name>
    <SMTP_Email_Address type="SZ">abc@cba.com</SMTP_Email_Address>
    <SMTP_Split_Messages type="DWORD">00000000</SMTP_Split_Messages>
</MessageAccount>
```

The batch must find `abc@cba.com` in this line and ignore all other mail:

```
    <SMTP_Email_Address type="SZ">abc@cba.com</SMTP_Email_Address>
```

At the beginning of the line there are 4 spaces.

The batch must extract the e-mail address `abc@cba.com` and rename the folders, every folder as the text in the XML file.

The folders tree is like this:

- folder / 1.oeaccount
- folder / 2.oeaccount
- folder / 3.oeaccount

Someone gave me this code but it doesn't work:

```
@echo off
setlocal
pushd "YourRootLocation"
set "search=<SMTP_Email_Address .*>[^ ][^ ]*@[^ ][^ ]*\.[^ ][^ ]*</SMTP_Email_Address>"
for /f "eol=: delims=" %%A in (
  'findstr /srmbc:"%search%" file1.txt^|sort /r'
) do for /f "tokens=2 delims=<>" %%B in (
  'findstr /rbc:"%search%" "%%A"'
) do if exist "%%A" for %%F in ("%%A\..") do if "%%~fF" neq "%CD%" (
  echo ren "%%~fF" "%%B"
  ren "%%~fF" "%%B"
)
popd
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you want to rename the parent folder of each `*.oeaccount` file to the e-mail address found in that file. For that something like this should work:

```
for /r "C:\root\folder" %%f in (*.oeaccount) do (
  for /f "delims=<> tokens=3" %%a in (
    'findstr "<SMTP_Email_Address" "%%~ff"'
  ) do (
    ren "%%~dpf" "%%~a"
  )
)
```

However, beware that, although it should work in this particular case, line-oriented processing of XML files (which is what `findstr` does) usually is **not** a good idea, because

```
<SMTP_Email_Address type="SZ">abc@cba.com</SMTP_Email_Address>
```

is just as valid XML as

```
<SMTP_Email_Address
    type="SZ">abc@cba.com</SMTP_Email_Address>
```

so re-wrapping of lines may foil your search patterns.

Comment: thank you alot for your Effort but this not work, thank you for your explain

Comment: I just noticed a mistake in the `ren` command. It's supposed to be `%%~dpf` not `%~ff`. Please try again.

Comment: @ Ansgar Wiechers - thank you - this is the msg i get for error after change the batch   C:\Users\MailN\Desktop\New folder>for
in (*.oeaccount) do (for /F "delims=<>
dress" "%~dpf"') do (ren "%~dpf" "%~a"

C:\Users\MailN\Desktop\New folder>(for
<SMTP_Email_Address" "C:\Users\me\D
C:\Users\me\Desktop\New folder\2 ra

C:\Users\me\Desktop\New folder>pause
Press any key to continue . . .

Comment: @Hauari That's unreadable. Please update your question with the code you're currently using and the error message it generates.

Comment: can any one help me about this

Comment: @Hauari Not unless you start following instructions.